# jquery/js - How to create toogle button to change height of box

Tags: javascript, jquery

How the correct way to create toggle button to change height of a box(changeHight)

```
$('.toggle').click(function() { 
    $('.changeHight').css('height','65px'); 
    $('.changeHight').css('height','32px');
});
```

Comment: That seems right, maybe there is a typo, `changeHight`  should be `changeHeight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to toggle a class using the [`.toggleClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Then let CSS handle the rest of the logic and add optional transitions.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() { 
    $('.changeHeight').toggleClass('changed');
});
```

```css
.changeHeight {
  background: #f00;
  height: 65px;
  transition: height 600ms ease-in-out;
}
.changed {
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">Toggle height</button>

<div class="changeHeight"><div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also do something like this:

```js
var toggled = false;
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $('.changeHeight').css('height', toggled ? '65px' : '32px');
  toggled = !toggled;
});
```

```css
.changeHeight {
  background: #f00;
  height: 65px;
  transition: height 600ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">Toggle height</button>

<div class="changeHeight"><div>
```

Comment: Oh,thank sir,your code are helpful for beginner as me :D

Answer (score 1):

Use classes and toggle them, or if that's not an option, toggle based on values

```
$('.toggle').click(function() { 
    $('.changeHight').css('height', function(_, height) {
        var h = parseInt( height.replace('px',''), 10);
        return (h === 65 ? 32 : 65) + 'px';
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w1b5k4h5/)

Comment: Thank adeneo,your code is working and also helped me in jquery skill.

Answer (score 0):

That seems right, maybe there is a typo, `changeHight` should be `changeHeight`

Comment: huhu,yup,I have defined in css file like that.. :D